# Lock asynchronouse method until callback

Tags: java, android, multithreading, testing, concurrency

I have a method to test

```
Service.signup(String username, String password, Callback listener);
```

I write a MockCallback to get the response

```
class MockCallback implements Callback {
   String res;
   public void done(String res) {
      this.res = res;
      this.notifyAll()
   }
}
```

I write a testcase for it, I must wait the `Service.signup` complete, to test the result.

```
MockCallback cb = new MockCallback();
sychronized(cb) {
   cb.wait();
   service.signup("foo", "bar", cb);
}
assertEquals(cb.res, "hello");
```

But it not work as I expected, the `cb.res` is `null`, it called `assertEquals(cb.res, "hello")` immediatly after `service.signup`, not what I want, how can I fix it?

Comment: It is nothing about Android. The `notify()` should be called on lock (waiting) object. `service.signup()` should be before wait line. And there are possible situation that service finished before wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CountDownLatch`:

```
class MockCallback implements Callback {
   private final CountDownLatch latch;
   String res;

   public MockCallback(CountDownLatch latch) { this.latch = latch; }

   public void done(String res) {
      this.res = res;
      latch.countDown();
   }
}
```

And in your test case:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch();
MockCallback cb = new MockCallback(latch);
service.signup("foo", "bar", cb);
latch.await(); // wait for latch to count down
assertEquals(cb.res, "hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the wait/notify pattern correctly.

**A.** notifyAll() should be synchronized using the same monitor as wait()

**B.** Producer call (=signup()) should not be within a synchronized block

**C.** wait() should be wrapped with a task-was-completed test loop, which in your case should test res != null.

**D.** And, it's a *really* good idea to make all your sync monitors to be final

Something like this:

```
class MockCallback implements Callback {
   String res;
   public synchronized void done(String res) { //<----------- now synchronized
      this.res = res;
      this.notifyAll()
   }
}

final MockCallback cb = new MockCallback(); //<----------- make monitor obj final


service.signup("foo", "bar", cb); //<----------- call not synchronized

sychronized(cb) {
   while (cr.res == null) { //<------------- wait in loop and check completion condition
      cb.wait();
   }
}
assertEquals(cb.res, "hello");
```